# R: Merging rasters of the same Julian date in loop

Tags: r, r-raster

I have got 250+ raster files (.tif) on my Windows 10 (x64) machine with the following example names:

```
"MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_1-AOD_QA.tif"
"MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_2-AOD_QA.tif"
"MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_4-AOD_QA.tif"
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_1-AOD_QA.tif"
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_3-AOD_QA.tif"
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_5-AOD_QA.tif"
```

In the above file names, `"AOD_QA_1-AOD_QA"` and `"AOD_QA_2-AOD_QA"` are different raster bands while "`A2018121`" is the Julian date that corresponds to `1 May 2018` calendar date and so on. Clearly, each date has multiple bands. Using R, I would like to merge all `.TIFF` files of the same date (e.g. `A2018121`) to a single (.tif) raster to achieve something like this:

```
"MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA.tif"
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA.tif"
```

How this could be done in R? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Is your question about finding the files that go together? Then provide a vector of a few example filenames. Or is about merging? If so, provide some simple raster objects (see ?raster::merge)

Comment: I have added more details to the question in an attempt to make it more clear. My question is about the merging of raster bands (.tif) of the same date to a single raster. I have also added expected output.

Answer (score 2):

With these filenames

```
ff = c("MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_1-AOD_QA.tif",
"MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_2-AOD_QA.tif",
"MYD19A.A2018121.h15v06.006.2018131152409.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_4-AOD_QA.tif",
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_1-AOD_QA.tif",
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_3-AOD_QA.tif",
"MYD19A.A2018122.h15v06.006.2018131152410.psrpgs_000501368212.AOD_QA_5-AOD_QA.tif")
```

You could do something like this

```
library(raster)
outpath <- ""
dates <- unique(substr(ff, 9, 15))
for (date in dates) {
    fd <- sort(grep(date, ff, value=TRUE))
    outfn <- file.path(outpath, paste0(substr(fd[1], 1, 67), ".tif"))
    print(fd)
    cat("--->", outfn, "\n\n")
    # now that we have the files, we can use "stack" and "writeRaster"
    # x <- stack(fd)
    # writeRaster(x, outfn)
}
```